# Не работает сортировка по двум полям

Tags: php, mysql

Есть простая таблица с 4 полями:
id(int), text(text), parent_id(int), date_x(timestamp)
Отсортировать надо что бы было так:

```
id date
--- ----------------
1   2017-04-29 18:01:03
2   2016-03-28 18:01:03
3   2015-04-27 18:01:03
```

Что бы было понятно в таблице хранятся статьи/сообщения эти статьи можно комментировать, так вот свежая статья должна находится в верху списка, а свежий комментарий наоборот внизу 
Вот этот запрос не работает:

```
SELECT id, articles.text, parent_id, articles.date FROM articles ORDER BY articles.date, id DESC
```

Пытался еще объединить 2 запроса с помощью UNION к примеру если parent_id > 0(комментарий) то DESC и если parent = 0(статья) то ASC, но тоже безрезультатно

Comment: Просто ORDER BY articles.date  ; - id там вроде как лишнее

Comment: В приведенном вами примере, либо не достаточно данных, либо сортировка по первому полю `ORDER BY id

Comment: в том то и дело что сортировка только происходит по одному из полей, а что бы по 2 это мне только разделить эту таблицу на 2 надо, то есть на комменты и статьи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно сортировать по дополнительному вычислимому столбцу.

для вашего случая подойдёт, например, числовое представление даты и времени, возвращаемое функцией `unix_timestamp()`. и условие добавить — если значение такого-то столбца равно нулю, то возвращать отрицательное значение.

пример (дополнительный столбец — `d2`):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21a008/6)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (p int, d date);

insert into t (p, d) values
    (0, '2017-04-10')
  , (0, '2017-04-20')
  , (1, '2017-04-15')
  , (2, '2017-04-16')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select p, d, if(p=0, -unix_timestamp(d), unix_timestamp(d)) d2 from t
  order by d2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21a008/6/0)**:

```
| p |                       d |          d2 |
|---|-------------------------|-------------|
| 0 | April, 20 2017 00:00:00 | -1492646400 |
| 0 | April, 10 2017 00:00:00 | -1491782400 |
| 1 | April, 15 2017 00:00:00 |  1492214400 |
| 2 | April, 16 2017 00:00:00 |  1492300800 |
```

---

в принципе, можно обойтись даже и без столбца, указав нужное условие прямо в `order by`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21a008/7)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (p int, d date);

insert into t (p, d) values
    (0, '2017-04-10')
  , (0, '2017-04-20')
  , (1, '2017-04-15')
  , (2, '2017-04-16')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t
  order by if(p=0, -unix_timestamp(d), unix_timestamp(d))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21a008/7/0)**:

```
| p |                       d |
|---|-------------------------|
| 0 | April, 20 2017 00:00:00 |
| 0 | April, 10 2017 00:00:00 |
| 1 | April, 15 2017 00:00:00 |
| 2 | April, 16 2017 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: я что-то не понимаю ? почему бы просто не сделать http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9f11c/1/0 (давно уже с mysql не возился)

Comment: `select * from t order by p asc, d desc;`

Comment: ну так сначала по одному полю сортируем, потом по другому, результат прям идентичный вашему получается.

Comment: да :) так сортировка по двум столбцам так и работает :)

Comment: а да :) я понял наконец...

Comment: спасибо, очень помогли!